# For a windows mobile app, building with Visual Studio in C++, how does one dynamically change a softkey menu to a button (and back)?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-mobile

I am building an application using VS2008, in C++, for Windows Mobile 6 and I want to change the tool bar associated with the left and right soft-keys. I know how to change them between menus and buttons before compilation by changgin the resources, (NOMENU), however, as the demands if my application change I want to be able to change a menu into a button and back.

It is not an option to follow the standard model of left button / right menu. I have tried always using two menus and catching the WM_INITMENUPOPUP when I want to treat one as a button, however, that leaves the menu pressed till focus changes which does not suit my purposes.

Thank you in advance.